# plot graph in a specific figure in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Actually, I am not clear that

```
fig_1 = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
...
```

Is the ploting like `plt.subplot(2,2,1)` and other `plt.` plot on the `fig_1` or system will automatically create a new empty figure?

Then how to plot something in a specific figure, for example:

```
fig_1 = plt.figure()
fig_2 = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
```

I want to subplot on `fig_2`.

Comment: Also see e.g. [multiple figures in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834216/how-to-handle-multi-figures-with-matplotlib-in-a-for-loop).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest so actually, when I write `fig_1 = plt.figure()`, every actions are taken on the `fig_1` until  a new `plt.figure()` is actived, the same as `plt.subplot(2,2,1) `?

Comment: Correct. This becomes quickly very cumbersome to remember and activate each figure and subplot in case you want to perform actions on different figures, so I would recommend using the object oriented style as shown in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a certain figure by e.g.

```
ax_1_1 = fig_1.add_subplot(2,2,1)
```

but this has a slightly different syntax (compare `plt.subplot()` against `fig.add_subplot()`)

So I would recommend to create figures with subplots already prepared vis `plt.subplots` which returns handles for figure and axes on the fly:

```
fig_1, axs_1 = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig_2, axs_2 = plt.subplots(3, 4)

axs_1[0, 0].plot(range(10))
axs_2[2, 3].plot(range(100))

fig_1.suptitle('Figure 1')
fig_2.suptitle('Figure 2')
```

etc. ...

Comment: thanks, how to take the actions such as `plt.xlabel('Spot')`, `plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--')` and `plt.legend(loc = 'best', prop={'size': 10})` for a `specific subplot(2,2,1)`?

Comment: Actually, I know the principle, but I am not familiar with the syntax of converting  `plt.` to `fig.`

Comment: You don't convert `plt` to `fig`. After `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)` `fig`contains the whole figure instance, while `ax` refers to a grid of axes. So you can write e.g. `ax[0, 0].set_xlabel('Spot')` or `ax[0, 1].axhline(y=0, linestyle='--')` or `ax[1, 1].legend(loc = 'best', prop={'size': 10})` Note that `fig.legend()`provides a single legend for all subplots in the latest matplotlib version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [figure.add_subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) which will return an ax linked to your figure on which you can plot your data. Look at [this page](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) to get a global view of the different objects used by matplotlib.